# JavaFx Разделение проекта на компоненты

Tags: java, javafx

Есть проект. Закидывает вводимые данные в таблицу. Как разделить этот проект на подклассы? То есть, отделить на 3 `fxml` файла. Главный,отдельно таблица и отдельно текстовое поле с кнопкой. И каждому `fxml` файлу контроллер.

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("tables.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 600, 400));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

 }

public class Controller implements Initializable {

    public TableView<InputObject> tableInfo;
    public TextArea inputArea;
    public Button inputButton;
    public TableColumn<InputObject, String> col1;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        col1.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("text"));
    }

    public void inputToTable() {
        if(inputArea.getText() != "") {
            tableInfo.getItems().addAll(new InputObject(inputArea.getText()));
            inputArea.clear();
        }
    }
}

public class InputObject {
    String text;

    public InputObject(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
}
```

и

```
<BorderPane fx:controller="sample.Controller" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <left>
      <TableView fx:id="tableInfo" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="330.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
        <columns>
          <TableColumn fx:id="col1" prefWidth="75.0" text="Output" />
        </columns>
         <columnResizePolicy>
            <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
         </columnResizePolicy>
      </TableView>
   </left>
   <center>
      <VBox alignment="TOP_CENTER" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <TextArea fx:id="inputArea" prefHeight="188.0" prefWidth="270.0" />
            <Button fx:id="inputButton" onAction="#inputToTable" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Input">
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets bottom="30.0" left="30.0" right="30.0" top="30.0" />
               </VBox.margin>
            </Button>
         </children>
      </VBox>
   </center>
</BorderPane>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class Main extends Application {

    private RootController rootController;
    private TableController tableController;
    private TextController textController;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        FXMLLoader loader;

        loader = new FXMLLoader( getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("./root.fxml"));
        loader.setController( rootController = new RootController() );
        BorderPane root = (BorderPane)loader.load();

        loader = new FXMLLoader( getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("./table.fxml"));
        loader.setController( tableController = new TableController() );
        root.setLeft( loader.load() );

        loader = new FXMLLoader( getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("./text.fxml"));
        loader.setController( textController = new TextController( tableController.getTable() ) );
        root.setRight( loader.load() );

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 600, 400));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}

class RootController{
    @FXML
    private void initialize() {}
}

class TableController{

    @FXML private TableView<InputObject> tableInfo;
    @FXML public TableColumn<InputObject, String> col1;

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        col1.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("text"));
    }

    public TableView getTable() {
        return tableInfo;
    }
}

class TextController{

    private final TableView tableInfo;

    public TextController( TableView tableInfo ) {
        this.tableInfo = tableInfo;
    }

    @FXML public TextArea inputArea;
    @FXML public Button inputButton;

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
    }

    @FXML
    public void inputToTable() {
//        нельзя так сравнивать строки
//        if(inputArea.getText() != "") {
        if( !inputArea.getText().equals( "" ) ) { // или !inputArea.getText().isEmpty()
            tableInfo.getItems().addAll(new InputObject(inputArea.getText()));
            inputArea.clear();
        }
    }
}
```

```
<!--root.fxml-->
<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"/>

<!--table.fxml-->
<TableView fx:id="tableInfo" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="330.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
  <columns>
    <TableColumn fx:id="col1" prefWidth="75.0" text="Output" />
  </columns>
   <columnResizePolicy>
      <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
   </columnResizePolicy>
</TableView>

<!--text.fxml-->
<VBox alignment="TOP_CENTER" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <TextArea fx:id="inputArea" prefHeight="188.0" prefWidth="270.0" />
      <Button fx:id="inputButton" onAction="#inputToTable" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Input">
         <VBox.margin>
            <Insets bottom="30.0" left="30.0" right="30.0" top="30.0" />
         </VBox.margin>
      </Button>
   </children>
</VBox>
```